# Modular Arithmetic proof .

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Show that there are infinitely many positive integers which are not the sum
of three squares. [Hint: what are the squares mod 8?] Investigate whether a  similar argument, working mod 16, could give a similar result about four squares.

Comment: Every positive integer is a sum of four or less squares. It is a proved theorem.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?  identifying the squares mod $8$, or using that to prove the claim?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner for the squares mod 8 I am not sure if they want a general form or just a list and either way I don't know how to use that for the proof

Comment: I suggest starting with the list. If it doesn't give the right answer straight away it will help get closer to the solution.

Comment: I agree with @NikiDiGiano

Comment: i have the list and numbers are missing but i don't know why this implies the result that we want

Comment: @MorenaDragomir By metaphor, suppose I have a collection of $\$1$ dollar bills and $\$5$ dollar bills.  Can I pay exactly $\$9$ for something using only two bills?  Using only three bills?  The possible sums I could make with two bills would be $1+1=2, 1+5=6,$ and $5+5=10$.  Why does $9$ not appearing there mean that I can't pay exactly $\$9$ using two bills?  What does this metaphor have to do with your problem?

Comment: what possible sums (modulo $8$) can you make of three numbers from the list?

Comment: If it *were* possible to pay exactly $\$9$ with my bills, it should have been one of the possible sums that I saw in that list since I showed all possible sums.  Since $9$ is not listed... that means its *not* possible.  So, for your problem...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner 0,1,2,3,6,9,12

Comment: $9$ and $12$ should be reduced mod $8$; also you missed $5$; but the key point is that $7$ is not on this list

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon the already provided hint:

Every square is one of ______ modulo $8$.

> Every square is one of $0,1,4$ modulo $8$.  (*Make sure you can explain why this is!*)

So, the possible results of sums of three squares modulo $8$ would be:

> $0+0+0, 0+0+1, 0+1+1, 1+1+1, 0+0+4, 0+1+4,\dots$.  (*Complete the list and simplify it to $0,1,2,\dots$ and make sure you can explain why it is*)

Now, what do you notice about this list?  Is there anything obvious that is missing from it?  Can you describe those numbers?

> What does the absence of a particular number from this list imply about numbers with that remainder modulo 8 and their ability to be expressed as a sum of three squares?

Comment: i have done the first parts correctly but i do not understand the last part